# Lambda Left Join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a LINQ query and I would like to handle the NULL values after performing a left join.

I have the code below:

```
var leftjoinlist = listA.GroupJoin(
        listB,
        a => a.Code,
        b => b.Code,
        (a, g) => g
    .SelectMany(new { Parent = a, Child = b })
    .DefaultIfEmpty(new { Parent = a, Child = a }))
    .SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

If child is null, I want to assign the parent instead. However I am getting a conversion error during assignment. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax to have an outer left join in your case:

```
listA
    .GroupJoin(listB, a => a.Code, b => b.Code, (a, g) => new {Parent = a, Childs = g})
    .SelectMany(arg => arg.Childs.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                   (arg1, c) => new {arg1.Parent, Child = c ?? arg1.Parent})
    .ToList();
```